# admin/ custome controller returns 404

Tags: magento2, 404-page, routes

I'm trying to create an admin route and the directories are:

```
app/code/<my_company>/<my_module_name>/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index
```

the code is

```
namespace Mastering\SampleModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $result */
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
        $result->setContents('Hello Admins!');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

and my ***routes.xml*** directory

```
app/code/Mastering/SampleModule/etc/Adminhtml/routes.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="mastering" frontName="mastering">
            <module name="Mastering_SampleModule"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

and after that I went to admin panel and disabled security keys.
now i go to myhost/admin/mastering

and it returns

> Magento Admin
> admin
> 404 Error
> Page not found.

my magento version is 2.4

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your path to routes.xml

There is Capital "A" in your "Adminhtml" directory which should be small 'a'

so your actual path should be

> app/code/Mastering/SampleModule/etc/**adminhtml**/routes.xml